# Flatten Multiple rows with mixed values into one row with grouping

Tags: group-by, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to take the following data ,which is stored as rows on a SQL server:

```
ID  Count   Takings
1   null    4413
1   null    6258
1   null    3809
1   613 null
1   6   null
1   875 null
1   349 null
1   116 null
2   null    6916
2   null    2209
2   null    5255
2   290 null
2   197 null
2   393 null
2   737 null
2   268 null
3   null    9272
3   null    2862
3   698 null
3   393 null
```

and flatten the result to one row with the columns aggregated as such

```
ID  Count   Takings
1   1959    14480
2   1885    1091
3   1091    12134
```

Any help would be much appreciated. This is on a SQL Azure. So 2012+ I guess

Many thanks for any help everyone

Wayne

Comment: I assume the value of `Takings` for ID `2` is a typo? I think the sum should be `6916+2209+5255 = 14380`.

Comment: You are right yeah :) Thought I'd checked that as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect job for `group by` query:

```
select
  [ID],
  sum([Count]) as [Count],
  sum([Takings]) as [Takings]
from
  Table1
group by ID
```

A `group by` combines data together based on each unique combination of the columns being grouped.  So for each unique value of `ID`, we aggregate the `sum` of `Count` and `Takings`.

Result ([**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8766/1)):

```
| ID | COUNT | TAKINGS |
|----|-------|---------|
|  1 |  1959 |   14480 |
|  2 |  1885 |   14380 |
|  3 |  1091 |   12134 |
```